# iOS: Groups in UIPickerView?

Tags: ios

Like the drop-down box (the `<select>` tag) in HTML, it has an element tag called `<optgroup>`.

I wonder is there any grouping feature in `UIPickerView`?

Comment: Would be nice to have an answer after 10 years...

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387902/how-do-i-add-section-titles-in-a-uipickerview, but not a native method.

Comment: Isn't it violating the app store design guidelines?

Comment: Not this one. Checked this doesn't mention in the guidelines.