# How to set title above each component of a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I implemented a UIPickerview with 2 components. I want to set a title above each one. How can I do that?

I don't want do place a separate label above the picker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add section titles in a UIPickerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387902/how-do-i-add-section-titles-in-a-uipickerview)

Comment: `UIPickerView` has no support for adding labels above each component. You either need to add labels (which you say you don't want to do for some reason), or you do what is suggested in the link by @the4kman.

Answer (score 2):

I often add an additional component to my `UIPickerView` with just one row and set that row's title to the header for the next component.

For example for an "hours and minutes" `UIPickerView`.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 4 //2 headers and 2 values
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
       return 1 //hours header
    } else if component == 1 {
       return 100 //hours
    } else if component == 2{
       return 1 //minutes header
    } else {
       return 4 //minutes
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return "Hours:" //header
    } else if component == 1 {
        return "\(row + 1)" //value
    } else if component == 2 {
        return "Minutes:" //header
    } else if component == 3 { 
        return "\(row * 15)" //value
    }
    return nil
}
```

The result will be this:

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj66i.png)

Comment: Is there a way to have a dynamic amount of rows for component:1 based on what row I selected for component:0?

Answer (score -1):

```
 func setHeadersForPickerView() {
    let labelWidth = deliveryPicker.frame.width / CGFloat(deliveryPicker.numberOfComponents)
    for index in 0..<pickerHeaders.count {
        let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: deliveryPicker.frame.origin.x + (labelWidth * CGFloat(index)), y: 10, width: labelWidth + 40, height: 20))
        label.text = pickerHeaders[index]
        label.textAlignment = .center
        deliveryPicker.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```